# Cloud connectivity for MQTT and AMQP?

Tags: cloud, amqp, mqtt

What is the difference between MQTT and AMQP in terms of cloud connectivity?
I need to compare these two protocols in terms of cloud connectivity/cooperation.
I found some evidence that AMQP works better but I still need to find out the differences.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cloud connectivity"? Brokers that support both protocols can be connected to across the internet

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The big difference here to point out is : are we speaking about AMQP 0.x or AMQP 1.0. They are two completely different protocols and only the latter is a ISO/IEC standard supported by the main open sources products like ActiveMQ and Artemis brokers, Qpid Proton clients and Qpid Dispatch Router. Products like RabbitMQ support AMQP 0.x (only with a plugin the version 1.0).
The big difference is that the AMQP 0.x defines the way a broker should be developed and have concepts like exchanges, queues and bindings.
No information about it in the AMQP 1.0 which is an application protocol on top of TCP/IP providing more abstraction and not specifying the way a broker should be developed.
The first big difference with MQTT is that AMQP 1.0 is a peer-to-peer protocol : you can use it between two peers, no need for a broker in the middle. Of course it's used for communication with broker providing store-and-forward mechanism. You can use it for request/reply pattern and for pub/sub. It has a built-in type system and messages provide metadata information.

MQTT is a lightweight protocol working only with a broker in the middle with no concept of queue (it can store messages when a client is offline using the "clean session" feature). It has another feature over AMQP like the "will" testment. It supports only pub/sub and have no metadata in the messages.

AMQP is more oriented to messaging than MQTT. It was created by JP Morgan for business transactions.

You can find a lot of information about them with in depth comparison.
If you need some resources and links please ask me ;)

Paolo.

Answer (score 26):

**AMQP**
 Two of the most important reasons to use AMQP are reliability and interoperability. As the name implies, it provides a wide range of features related to messaging, including reliable queuing, topic-based publish-and-subscribe messaging, flexible routing, transactions, and security. AMQP exchanges route messages directly—in fanout form, by topic, and also based on headers.

**MQTT**
The design principles and aims of MQTT are much more simple and focused than those of AMQP—it provides publish-and-subscribe messaging (no queues, in spite of the name) and was specifically designed for resource-constrained devices and low bandwidth, high latency networks such as dial up lines and satellite links, for example. Basically, it can be used effectively in embedded systems.

I recommend you to use **AMQP**.

Source: [http://blogs.vmware.com/](http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html)